# Applications of the Tate-Shafarevich group in class field theory

Tags: applications, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

I'm studyng a course on class field theory and Galois cohomology this semester, and my lecturer said in one of the lectures that the Tata-Shafarevich group is indeed important is class field theory, and he mentioned that this group has a role in computing the Brauer group of some field, bet he didn't mentioned more than that.

What are the applications of the Tate-Shafarevich gruop in class field theory? I know we can prove some properties of this group by the Selmer group which is close to class field theory, but I'm intrested in the applications of the other direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First one would need to define *which* Tate-Shafarevich group we’re speaking about… CFT is basically about $\mathbb{G}_m$ and by Hilbert’ 90 this one is somewhat trivial… The first two inequalities show that $TS^2(\mathbb{G}_m)$ for global fields must vanish as well. So I really don’t know which one you’re talking about…

Comment: @Aphelli, say the Tate-Shafarevich group over an elliptic curve

Comment: I’d say that the relationship is the other way around… The Tate-Shafarevich group of an elliptic curve is an object which is too poorly understood to have “applications”. On the other hand, you can use CFT (among others!) to construct an alternate bilinear map into $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, whose kernel on both sides is the divisible part (conjectured to be zero but this is, of course, wide open).

Comment: @Aphelli interesting… Do you have any references? I’d like to read about it!

Comment: The keyword about this part seems to be “Cassels-Tate pairing”. Finiteness remarks should be explained in texts about elliptic curves. I’m not sure where you should look for the general structure facts that everyone takes for granted. For finiteness results for elliptic curves, the best-known ones are due to Rubin (CM) and Kolyvagin (analytic rank one).